# How can I use a Google Apps nickname with push Gmail on iOS4?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, iphone

I have a Google Apps for your domain account that I have used for several years. I originally set up this account with a very generic username as a spam protection measure since I knew I could setup additional nicknames for the account and send from those instead. I figured that if I ever started getting a ton of spam at my primary account, this would make it easier to just block messages sent to the current account and switch to another nickname.

When I first got my iPhone 3GS, push Gmail was not an option for me since only one exchange (push gmail uses this protocol) account was allowed, and I needed to connect to the exchange server at the office for my work email and calendar. With this limitation, I set up my Google Apps Gmail account through IMAP. This allowed me to log in with the basic username like I have to when going to the web interface, but still allowed me to setup the email account on the phone to send as the primary nickname I use for that account.

Now that iOS4 allows multiple exchange accounts, I am able to set up push Gmail. However, even though I can enter the account information just like I did with the IMAP setup and save It initially, the email account automatically gets changed back to the basic username after I try to load the mailbox for the first time. Therefore, no matter which nickname the message was sent to, any messages I send show that they are sent from this basic account (which I truthfully don't want people to see at all for the spam protection reason above if I could have the choice).

Is there a way to setup push Gmail using the nickname that I want to on the iPhone? If not, is the problem an iOS problem, and Exchange/ActiveSync problem, or a push Gmail limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has this listed as a [known limitation](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139635).  The only thing you could do is add the nickname as a 2nd email account (not exchange) on the phone and then use that for sending email.

Comment: Which is what I have been doing, but it's obviously inconvenient. Normally when I receive an email through push, I tend to respond in that account rather than switching.

Comment: You can respond in the same account, just tap the cc/bcc/from line and change the from address.  The other account has to be enabled so your counts in the badge will be off, but you can read from the exchange inbox and reply from there as well.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you setup IMAP email for your nickname as explained here:
http://www.mysysadmintips.com/index.php/mobile-devices/42-iphone-sending-emails-from-gmail-alias-nickname
Then setup gmail via Exchange only for contacts and calendar. That way you will have only one email account to deal with. Or I'm missing something?